# Typing a subset of a constant in Flow.js without duplication

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In the following snippet, I have a function that should return one element from a constant.

```
// @flow
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']

function getLetter(i: number): 'a' | 'b' | 'c' {
  return letters[i]
}
```

How do I avoid typing all entries in that constant twice, once for the content and once for the type?

Since constant's type can be inferred, how do I declare a type that is just one element of that inferred type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow does not have a way to do this, sorry. If you use this type a lot you can declare a `Letters` type, but that still requires listing the options once for the type and once for the runtime array.